# Changing the visibility of TabBar elements in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation

I have navigation in my TabBar, I need, if the user is not authorized, then "My profile" was not displayed, and if authorized, then "Registration" and "Authorization" were not displayed. How can this be done?

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Главная" Icon="icon_home.png">
    <ShellContent Route="MainPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Челленджи" Icon="icon_carbon.png">
    <ShellContent Route="ChallengesPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ChallengesPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Сообщества" Icon="icon_community.png">
    <ShellContent Route="CommunityPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:CommunityPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Погода" Icon="icon_weather.png">
    <ShellContent Route="WeatherPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:WeatherPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Мой профиль" Icon="icon_profile.png">
    <ShellContent Route="UserProfilePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:UserProfilePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Регистрация" Icon="icon_reg.png">
    <ShellContent Route="RegistrationPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:RegistrationPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
<FlyoutItem Title="Авторизация" Icon="icon_login.png">
    <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IsVisible="{Binding IsAuthorizedUser}"` to dynamically change the visibility of the UserProfilePage.

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Мой профиль" Icon="icon_profile.png" IsVisible="{Binding IsAuthorizedUser}">
    <ShellContent Route="UserProfilePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:UserProfilePage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

In your ViewModel or Code-behind, you may need [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to change **IsAuthorizedUser** to `true` or `false` based on whether the user is authorized or not.